# Why is it faster to print to the javascript console than printing to C++ console?

Tags: javascript, c++, performance, console, performance-testing

I've noticed that it seems to take longer to print to the console in C++ than it does in Javascript, but I would have expected the opposite.  I created these two fizzbuzz tests in JS and C++:

**JS**

```
window.onload = function() 
{
   console.time("test");

   for(var i = 0; i < 10001; i++) 
   {

       if(i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) 
       {            
          console.log(i + " -- fizzbuzz \n");
       }
       else if(i % 3 == 0) 
       {
          console.log(i + " -- fizz \n");
       }
       else if(i % 5 == 0) 
       {
          console.log(i + " -- buzz \n");
       }                
   }

   console.timeEnd("test"); 
}
```

**C++**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{

std::clock_t start;
double duration;

start = std::clock();

for (int i = 0; i < 10001; i++) 
{
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
    {
        printf("%d -- fizzbuzz \n", i);
    }
    else if (i % 3 == 0)
    {
        printf("%d -- fizz \n", i);
    }
    else if (i % 5 == 0)
    {
        printf("%d  buzz \n", i);
    }
}

duration = ((std::clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

printf("duration: %f \n", duration);

std::getchar();

return 0;
}
```

**Results**

JS

492.54ms
498.77ms
502.36ms

C++

2017ms
2149ms
2357ms

Can anyone explain why a compiled language such as C++ would perform ~4 times slower than an interpreted, weakly typed language such as Javascript?  I realize there is probably a problem with how I conducted the test, but I'm just curious about what the problem could be.

Comment: How are you compiling? Be sure to enable optimizations.

Comment: obvious question, did you compile with optimizations enabled?

Comment: To be fair, you preform one more iteration in the c++ case than in the javascript case.

Comment: I also doubt you're reading your results properly.

Comment: The source code is just one factor. You also need to specify exactly how it was compiled and how the compiled binary code was started. You also need to specify exactly how the JavaScript code was started.

Comment: You're comparing the output speed of a browser console and the terminal console (or wherever the C++ program prints), not the speed of JS and C++.

Comment: I have optimizations enabled, but that comment did make me think that I was running the C++ code in debug mode, and after running it in Release mode a second was shaved off (i.e. ~1500ms).  Again, I'm sure I have made a mistake somewhere or fundamentally don't understand something.  I'm curious about what that something might be.

Comment: You're not testing your C++ code, you're testing the speed of your terminal. Try redirecting to a file or `/dev/null` and measuring the time.

Comment: @JJJ Yeah, I feel like I worded the question that way too.  Why is printing to the browser console faster than the terminal console?

Comment: @Mat that's not my question though.

Comment: "Can anyone explain why a compiled language such as C++ would perform ~4 times slower than an interpreted, weakly typed language such as Javascript?" - this is your question, as you wrote it. Your "test" for this assertion is flawed.

Comment: "stdafx.h" suggests you're running this inside Visual Studio, is that right? I tested the C++ version in the Mac terminal and it ran in 8 ms. Node.js version in the same terminal was about 100 ms. In the browser console, 550 ms.

Comment: "Why is it faster to print to the javascript console than printing to C++ console?"  No, that is my question.  The word "perform" in your quote implies printing to the console (which is obvious in the context of the whole post).

Comment: That's not the question in your post. BTW the Javascript console in your browser is likely implemented in C++, your console possibly C or C++. Javascript doesn't have much to do with anything here.

Comment: @JJJ Yes!  I wrote this using Visual Studio.  So what does this imply about the VS compiler?

Comment: Nothing. It implies that "C++ console" (whatever that is) is slower to print text than your browser's console is.

Comment: But why?  Why would the Windows console perform so much worse than a browser console?

Comment: 5 lines per millisecond is good enough for any purpose. There's no point in optimizing it any further.

Comment: @JJJ Ok, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing it in two different environments. To make it a fair test, I decided to test it in similar environments (same host, 2GHz AMD  A10-6800K processor as reported by `cat /proc/cpuinfo`):

Javascrtipt - using `node` binary version 0.10.25 on Linux executed from bash prompt. Results were consistent around 83ms. I had to remove `window.onload` wrapper, otherwise it was your code as is.

C++ - I had to remove the inclusion of `stdafx.h` to get it to compile. I also removed the call to `getchar()` as it was unnecessary. I compiled with g++ 4.8.4 with defaults and again ran it from bash prompt. The results varied between 10ms and 20ms.

When I redirected the standard output to a file, Javascript executed in 42ms, while C++ took 1 ms.

Which is a result that would be in the range of what one would expect when comparing a native binary compiled vs just-in-time compiled languages for this type of workload. Note however, that when the code is I/O heavy, as in your example, the difference will be largely negated, and if you test in different I/O subsystems, the one with the faster I/O will win regardless of the efficiency of the rest of the code.

I believe the 2000 ms order of magnitude result you are observing in C++ is connected to the console you are using (Windows default CMD.EXE ?) being not very efficient with the standard output processing.

Note, that I did verify with `strace` that in both cases in my test I/O was being done in a similar way - repeated calls to `write()` - one per line. If one was buffering, for example, and the other was not, it could have made a difference big enough to negate the speed differences in the rest of the code.

Comment: I run it on Windows 10 and get 100 ms, whether run from the console or from the VS IDE. The OP is doing something wrong.

Comment: I recompiled using g++ using with the -O3 flag and got it down to 150 ms.